# How to use an open drain signal to power a relay/MOSFET package?

Tags: mosfet, open-drain

I have a controller with a particular signal output (open drain, which I believe provides a ground when activated?) with an internal circuit breaker limiting to 175 mA that I want to use to drive a [Pololu 12 V relay MOSFET package](https://www.pololu.com/product/2482):

[image: Pololu Basic SPDT Relay Carrier with 12VDC Relay schematic]

Can I simply put 12 V on the Pololu's EN & Vdd (pins 2 & 3), and then put my controllers signal output on the Pololu pin 1 which goes to GND & the FET's source)?  My only real concern here is connecting +12 V to the FETs gate there, will it then channel such as to allow too much current from my 12 V supply? Also, how could I do calcs to make sure the FET's source connection to my controller won’t exceed 175 mA?

Or is my whole scheme here wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EN pin from the Pololu board is used to turn the relay on and off; a HIGH input (more than about 3V for the MOSFET they used) will turn the relay on and connect the COM terminal to the NO terminal, a LOW input will turn the relay off and connect the COM terminal to the NC terminal.  VDD and ground can be left connected; there is no need to disconnect them.

The EN pin is pulled down to ground on the Pololu board.  You could hook it up like so, using a PNP transistor to turn on the BSS138, which has a Vgs, max of 20V.  Your open drain output will sink less than 1mA so no worries about the circuit breaker.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7crNO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>